# How to filter PostgresSQL query result dependent on value on some column?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
SELECT
    time as "time",
    tag as "tag",
    value as "value"
FROM metrics
WHERE 
     tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A' OR   tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A' OR   tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A' OR  tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A'
GROUP BY 2, 1, 3
ORDER BY time desc
LIMIT 4
```

Which results in this:

[image]

Instead of returning all the 4 rows, I'd like to return the column which has a value "1". How can I achieve this?

Comment: `WHERE value = 1`???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want it to show the column with value = 1, you already have [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68224132/15915329).
With mi answer you select all the columns with values different to 0.

```
SELECT
    time as "time",
    tag as "tag",
    value as "value"
FROM metrics
WHERE 
     value != 0 AND (
     tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A' OR   tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A' OR   tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A' OR  tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A' )
GROUP BY 2, 1, 3
ORDER BY time desc
LIMIT 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a subquery if you only care about those four rows:

```
SELECT m.*
FROM (SELECT time as "time", tag as "tag", value as "value"
      FROM metrics
      WHERE tag IN ('KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A', 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A', 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A', 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A')
      GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
      ORDER BY time desc
      LIMIT 4
     ) m
WHERE value = 1;
```

But, I wonder if this does what you want more simply:

```
SELECT time as "time", tag as "tag", value as "value"
FROM metrics
WHERE tag IN ('KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A', 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A', 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A', 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A') AND
      value = 1
ORDER BY time DESC;
```

No aggregation.  No limiting.  Just return the matching rows with `value = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT time as "time", tag as "tag", value as "value" FROM metrics 
WHERE value = 1 AND (tag = 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_32A' OR   tag 
= 'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_63A' OR   tag = 
'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_80A' OR  tag = 
'KEB1.DB_IN.01.STATUS_CMD.A_LIM_125A' )
GROUP BY 2, 1, 3
ORDER BY time desc
LIMIT 4;
```

This should work.